# Allow all rule for one interface using firewalld

Tags: centos, firewalld, private

I have two interfaces in my CentOS-7 VPS. I want to allow all access to one interface(eth1, that is my private network). I'd change zone of eth1 to home  how can i add a rule to allow everything on that interface ??

Answer (score 9):

The natural way is setting the right **target** to your zone:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=YOUR_ZONE --set-target=ACCEPT
```

Set the target of a permanent zone.  target is one of: default, ACCEPT, DROP, %%REJECT%%

Answer (score 4):

You can use **Rich Rule** concept of `firewalld` for this. 
Try following rule :-

```
firewall-cmd --zone=home --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="0.0.0.0/0" accept'
```

Check your rule :-

`firewall-cmd --list-all --zone=home`